# "invertible function" is the same thing as "one to one correspondence" which is the same thing as "bijection"?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse, inverse-function

It looks like "invertible function" is the same thing as "one to one correspondence" which is the same thing as "bijection" ... so why is there three words for one thing? Seems useless

Comment: “Invertible function” may be different from the other two depending on the context. For example, in topology, not every bijection is invertible (because not every continuous bijection has a continuous inverse). As to “bijection” vs. “one-to-one correspondence”, the term “bijection” is more modern. It is not uncommon for the same concept to have received different names because of historical development.

Comment: Terminology is created, used and modifed by a huge amount of people throughout the world, especially for such a basic notion. It is not surprising that different terms exist.

Comment: What about in real numbers? Then is it all the same thing? invertible function = bijection = one to one correspondence?

Comment: Metric vs. imperial. Get used to it, its not going away.

Comment: One that threw me for a while was that some authors use the term Hilbert space for a separable Hilbert space.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I've never heard that notion of “inverible”. A continuous bijection with continuous inverse is called homeomorphism. I've never heard “invertible” be used to mean anything but “the inverse exists”.

Comment: @celtschk: Yes; but “the inverse exists” is not the same thing as “bijective [on underlying sets]”, even when “bijective” makes sense (concrete categories). I don’t think you are disagreeing with what I said! What “notion of ‘invertible’” do you read in my comment?

Comment: @celtschk: If you are working in a given category, “the inverse exists” means “the inverse exists *in the category*”.

Comment: @terrace: “What about in real numbers?” Depends on the context; if all you care about is set theoretically, yes, the three things are equivalent.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: So how do you define a bijection in a category other than SET?

Comment: @celtschk: When the category is concrete (objects are sets, arrows are set-theoretic functions between underlying sets) bijective means that the image under the forgetful functor is bijective. “Bijective” doesn’t mean anything without a forgetful functor to set. You don’t use “bijection” in non-concrete categories (nor do you use “injection” or “surjection”).

Answer (score 1):

The indentity map from Q into R is injective (1 to 1 as neophites call it) but it is not invertible (except as that computerist fantansy of a partial function).

Comment: You're confusing a one-to-one *function* (which indeed merely means that the function is an injection) with a one-to-one *correspondence* (which is a bijection). Yes, it's an utterly confusing terminology. The question used the latter.

Comment: It should be abandoned.  As I said @celtschk, 1 to 1 is alas, what neophytes are taught to use.  Technical terms unfortunately, are considered too difficult for our instant gratification kids to learn,

Comment: I agree that one of the uses should be abandoned, but I disagree which one: IMHO it is the use of "one-to-one" for injective that should be abandoned. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to decide that. But that's besides the point, as the OP clearly used the term one-to-one correspondence, which means bijection, and it is 100% clear that the OP didn't mean injection here.

Answer (score 0):

- Two  predicates ( here " being invertible" and " being bijective") may have the same extension ( apply to exactly the same set of objects) while being intensionally ( conceptually) different.
- It would make no sense to atttempt at showing that all bijective functions are bijective.

But it makes sense to prove that all bijectve functions are invertible, and reciprocally.

The *conceptual* distinction justifies the existence of 2 distinct terms.